# How can I make a pseudo-dynamic Stored procedure / CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, pivot-table

I am trying to be a good 'Netizen and explain my issue as simply as possible.
Here is some sample code I whipped up to illustrate.  The Dynamic SQL returns the results I need to see, but in the tools I have available to me, I have text size and functional limitations.

Effectively, I'd like to wrap the Dynamic SQL into a CTE, Parameterized view or stored Procedure so I can just say SELECT * FROM GetStudentCourseCompletionByProgram('2') or EXEC GetStudentCourseCompletionByProgram('2') to get the dynamic results I need, but I don't know how to get there. If needed I am able to remove the 'dynamic' aspect of it and hard code it to return 10 COURSE columns (so 12 total) and just assume that no program will ever be associated to more than 10 courses.

Thanks for any help you all can give!

```
USE [tempdb]
GO

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM SYS.tables WHERE name = 'STUDENTS') DROP TABLE STUDENTS
CREATE TABLE STUDENTS ( ID INT PRIMARY KEY, NAME VARCHAR(50))

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM SYS.tables WHERE name = 'PROGRAMS') DROP TABLE PROGRAMS
CREATE TABLE PROGRAMS ( ID INT PRIMARY KEY, NAME VARCHAR(50))

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM SYS.tables WHERE name = 'COURSES') DROP TABLE COURSES
CREATE TABLE COURSES (ID INT PRIMARY KEY, NAME VARCHAR(50)) 

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM SYS.tables WHERE name = 'STUPROGRAMS') DROP TABLE STUPROGRAMS
CREATE TABLE STUPROGRAMS (ID INT PRIMARY KEY, STUDENT_ID INT, PROGRAM_ID INT) 

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM SYS.tables WHERE name = 'PROGCOURSES') DROP TABLE PROGCOURSES
CREATE TABLE PROGCOURSES (ID INT PRIMARY KEY, PROGRAM_ID INT, COURSE_ID INT)

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM SYS.tables WHERE name = 'ENROLLMENTS') DROP TABLE ENROLLMENTS
CREATE TABLE ENROLLMENTS (ID INT PRIMARY KEY, STUDENT_ID INT, COURSE_ID INT)

INSERT INTO STUDENTS VALUES (1,'Caimbul'),(2,'Quassnoi'),(3,'Zohar'),(4,'Mike K'),(5,'Jeff');
INSERT INTO PROGRAMS VALUES (1,'Program1'),(2,'Program2');
INSERT INTO COURSES VALUES (1,'Course1'),(2,'Course2'),(3,'Course3'),(4,'Course4'),(5,'Course5');
INSERT INTO STUPROGRAMS VALUES (1,1,1),(2,2,1),(3,3,1),(4,4,1),(5,1,2),(6,2,2),(7,5,2);
INSERT INTO PROGCOURSES VALUES (1,1,1),(2,1,2),(3,1,3),(4,2,1),(5,2,3),(6,2,4),(7,2,5);
INSERT INTO ENROLLMENTS VALUES (1,1,1),(2,1,2),(3,1,3),(4,1,4),(5,1,5),(7,2,2),(8,2,3),(11,3,1),(12,3,2),(14,3,4),(16,4,1),(18,4,3),(19,4,4),(23,5,3),(25,5,5);

-- Dynamic PIVOT Gives me the results I want. 
--But I need it in a contained CTE Select query with a Program_ID parameter, or a Stored Procedure (with P.ID Param)
DECLARE @T AS TABLE(y INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);

DECLARE
@cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@y    AS INT,
@sql  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

-- Construct the column list for the IN clause
SET @cols = STUFF(
(SELECT N',' + QUOTENAME(y) AS [text()]
FROM (SELECT C.ID AS Y FROM PROGCOURSES PC JOIN COURSES C ON PC.COURSE_ID=C.ID WHERE PC.PROGRAM_ID = '2' ) AS Y
ORDER BY y   FOR XML PATH('')),1, 1, N'');

-- Construct the full T-SQL statement
-- and execute dynamically
SET @sql = N'SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT S.NAME, S.ID AS StudentID, PC.COURSE_ID, E.ID
FROM STUPROGRAMS SP JOIN STUDENTS S ON SP.STUDENT_ID = S.ID 
JOIN PROGRAMS P ON SP.PROGRAM_ID = P.ID
JOIN PROGCOURSES PC ON SP.PROGRAM_ID = PC.PROGRAM_ID
OUTER APPLY (
  SELECT TOP 1 INE.*, C.NAME
  FROM COURSES C 
  LEFT JOIN ENROLLMENTS INE ON C.ID = INE.COURSE_ID AND INE.STUDENT_ID = S.ID
  WHERE PC.COURSE_ID = C.ID
ORDER BY INE.ID DESC) AS E
WHERE P.ID = ''2'') SOURCE
PIVOT (
  COUNT(SOURCE.ID)
  FOR COURSE_ID IN (' + @cols + N') ) AS PIV
ORDER BY NAME;';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
GO
```

---

Deleted previous edits / explanations of my issue.

Comment: Any specific reason you don't output the results in tabular form, with each course on its row, and do the pivot on the presentation layer?

Comment: So much text, so little usefull information... Please read [ask].

Comment: Also, on SQL Server the output of stored procedures is not fixed

Comment: Why do you need your stored proc to return a constant schema? Also, I'm getting a very confused picture of your table relationships and layout. Can you show us some sample data?

Comment: @Quassnoi: I would do that, but unfortunately I am limited in the tools I am allowed to use.. Client demands..

Comment: Too much to read, please consider adding code in code blocks or some screenshots.

Comment: Sorry, too long. Skipping. Next question.

Comment: @Mike-k: I've now put in a code block illustrating showing samples of what I have and where I want to go..

Comment: @Caimbul: OK, that's cleared up my earlier confusion, but now I'm not clear what your question is. Obviously you know how to write a pretty complex query, including dynamic SQL - so what's stopping you just compiling that as a stored procedure? Are you asking how to write a stored procedure with a passed parameter? - because that seems at odds with the complexity of the code you've already written...

Comment: @MikeK. Well normal Select queries I'm pretty good with. The Dynamic SQL I pieced together with my queries and some tutorials online. However when I tried to put it into a stored procedure (again by looking up examples online.) I was getting errors, and found some links saying that Stored procedures can't use Dynamic SQL because it needs a consistant schema to process.. Which led me to post my question here to see how I can create this solution.  Also, I want it to run fast. :)

Comment: @Caimbul: Stored procedures can certainly use dynamic SQL, no worries. See answer below, which works when I run it in my environment. No idea how fast it'll be, though. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this seems to work:

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER, ANSI_NULLS ON 
GO
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.GetStudentCourseCompletionByProgram') AND OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsProcedure') = 1)
DROP PROCEDURE dbo.GetStudentCourseCompletionByProgram
GO  

CREATE PROC dbo.GetStudentCourseCompletionByProgram (@program INT)
AS

DECLARE
    @cols NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @y    INT,
    @sql  NVARCHAR(MAX);

 -- Construct the column list for the IN clause
 SET @cols = STUFF(
            (SELECT N',' + QUOTENAME(y) AS [text()]
       FROM (SELECT C.ID AS Y
               FROM PROGCOURSES PC
               JOIN COURSES C ON PC.COURSE_ID=C.ID
              WHERE PC.PROGRAM_ID = @program ) AS Y
           ORDER BY y
       FOR XML PATH('')),1, 1, N'');

-- Construct the full T-SQL statement
-- and execute dynamically
SET @sql = N'SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT S.NAME, S.ID AS StudentID, PC.COURSE_ID, E.ID
FROM STUPROGRAMS SP JOIN STUDENTS S ON SP.STUDENT_ID = S.ID 
JOIN PROGRAMS P ON SP.PROGRAM_ID = P.ID
JOIN PROGCOURSES PC ON SP.PROGRAM_ID = PC.PROGRAM_ID
OUTER APPLY (
SELECT TOP 1 INE.*, C.NAME
FROM COURSES C 
LEFT JOIN ENROLLMENTS INE ON C.ID = INE.COURSE_ID
AND INE.STUDENT_ID = S.ID
WHERE PC.COURSE_ID = C.ID
ORDER BY INE.ID DESC) AS E
WHERE P.ID =' + cast(@program as nvarchar) + ') SOURCE
PIVOT (
COUNT(SOURCE.ID)
FOR COURSE_ID IN (' + @cols + N') ) AS PIV
ORDER BY NAME;';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;

GO 

GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.GetStudentCourseCompletionByProgram TO standard
```

Then call it with `EXEC GetStudentCourseCompletionByProgram 2` (or `1`, or whatever takes your fancy).

Comment: Awesome Thanks! (I removed the grant permissions because I don't have a 'standard' user.) Either way that rocks..